# OAuth2Service missing in WSO2 IS 5.2.0 Admin Services

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I recently updated my environment from WSO2 IS 5.0.0 to WSO2 IS 5.2.0. My environment consists of 2 machines that are creating a cluster (using the WKA membership scheme and Load Balancer(AWS ELB) with sticky session enabled). I am using MySQL(not the default H2 database). The machines on which the IS is deployed are Windows Server 2012 R2 (EC2 AWS machines).

I am also using the IS admin services. After I upgraded my environment to WSO2 IS 5.2.0 I noticed that the following service is missing:
https://url:port/services/OAuth2Service?wsdl
Is this intentional (due to the change in the API) or it is related to some misconfiguration during the upgrade? If this is intentional, is there a similar service that exposes similar functionality?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OAuth2AuthzEndpoint and OAuth2TokenEndpoint to the same.

Thanks
Roger

Answer (score 0):

`Oauth2Service` is no longer exposed as an Admin service (From 5.1.0). Instead it is exposed as an OSGi Service.

Comment: Is there a documentation about how these WSO2 IS OSGi services could be consumed in another C# or Java application through http/https? I am asking because I am not so familiar with OSGi services. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, why do want to use this service? You better to use OAuth2AuthzEndpoint and OAuth2TokenEndpoint to issue authorization codes and access tokens